# Cypress tests fail when running headless but pass when running on Cypress interface

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, cypress, headless

I can run my test script on the Cypress interface with npx cypress open. In this case test runs pass. But when I run the same test script headless, it fails. What can be the cause of this issue?

I run the tests always behind OpenVPN both when running headless or on Cypress interface. This is required due to authentication API.

[image]
[image]

I wanted to mention that, not always the same tests are failed. While testing headless than my tests fails randomly. But when I run these tests on the Cypress interface everything passes without any error.
[image]

OpenVPN is connected.
[image]

This is the HTML element:
Every test creates new work order via API. So for every test work order title changes with a new `workorder-title` one, I leave DOM here to show DOM the design.

`<div class="workorder-title">21-270073 / EM / -</div>`  
[image]

Comment: please show us the element in HTML format that you are trying to find. Don't upload image, paste HTML code

Comment: I don't think it is about HTML,  test normally work without problem when I open it on cypress interface.  but ok of course i share HTML :)

Comment: @BarışCanAteş, I had the same issue and was so much frustrated, but unfortunately I can't remember correctly what the cause was. It was something related to the URL I was visiting. I think somehow the `baseUrl` got messed up , and headless could not handle it.

Comment: @DarkoRiđić Thank you so much. My problem is very similar to yours, Do you remember how did you fix it?

Comment: @BarışCanAteş, does your website rely on localstorage maybe?

Comment: @DarkoRiđić yes, I use local storage to get authorization tokens to feed API requests. my first test case is generally stuck at the API request step but sometimes passes, it looks strange. When it is stuck at API req step then it sees the authorization token as null. Today I was working on this problem to find out why this is happening.

Comment: @BarışCanAteş, does the URL you're visiting maybe have a double slash "//"? If so, try removing one slash. Please check this

Comment: @DarkoRiđić cy.visit('https://***.******.com/')  this is the my URL.

Comment: @BarışCanAteş, this might and does sound stupid, but try removing the slash at the end.

Comment: I tried nothing happened, but I found something interesting. My website uses a refresh policy which is working stable while the web opens the cypress interface. But that looks not working on the headless run.

Comment: Sad to hear. But one thing is for sure: The cause lies somewhere on frontend. The website I had problems with, was doing something with localstorage non-stop. It was not an "ordinary" website.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. First of all everything, there were two different issues to solve about my Stackoverflow issue.

1- my API request came as unauthorized.

I was getting authorization tokens like this--> `anyVariable=localStorage.getItem('autToken')`

This was work without a problem while I using `npx Cypress open` because Cypress works extremely quickly on the interface and `anyVariable` fully filled by token and works without any problem.

But while using headless mode then cypress gets slower so that's why Cypress sent API req before `anyVariable` fully filled by token and responses as unauthorized.

I read some issues and articles about Cypress and Getting item by LocalStorage. People said that this usage "anyVariable=localStorage.getItem('autToken')" to get item local storage works as async  So that's why I used `cy.` command to solve my problem and my attempt completely solved my problem.

I solved the problem by using the chainable cypress method.

```
    cy.window()
        .then((window) => {
            return window.localStorage.getItem('anyVariable')
        })
        .then((token) => {
            setAnyVariable(token)
        })
```

2- The second problem was caused by one of our frontend component which refreshes the newly created item list to be newly created items visible. It was strange because that component was works stable when I run my tests with `npx cypress open`.

Why I explained that if you face with similar issue then you can try to check your frontend components.

I working on a solution to that problem right now.